# Working With Youtube Feed in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app in which i want to display the list of Youtube videos from my channel. It should allow the user to play the video also.

Is there any third party library which can be used for Windows Phone 8 for working with Youtube ??

Answer (score 0):

YouTube vedios can be played using MytoolKit Library
http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube